Is there a function or argument to remove quotes when writing to csv file in python
I am appending a large amount of data and writing to a csv file.
Data is a list that is appended to an example:
data = ['438.0337145,438.0178423,0.0158\n', '438.0497017,438.0337145,0.01598\n']
with open(uuidCSV, 'w') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=",")
    wr.writerow(data)

When I open the csv file the output is:
"438.0337145,438.0178423,0.0158
","438.0497017,438.0337145,0.01598

Using the below method creates:
with open(uuidCSV, 'w') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=",", escapechar="\"")
    wr.writerow(data)

Creates:
 438.0337145",438.0178423",0.0158"
,438.0497017",438.0337145",0.01598"

Is there a way to remove the quotes so the output is:
438.0337145,438.0178423,0.0158
438.0497017,438.0337145,0.01598


With this specific data, you don't need to use the csv module at all.  Just write() each list element to the file directly.

You have selected quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, which tells the writer to quote all fields. But you also have commas in your data fields, so the csv file would be malformed without the quotes.

@OldBoy I updated the example I have tried both ways.  I skipped adding the quote none option.

So the data is already in CSV format? Then why are you using the csv module in the first place?

@JohnGordon I could do that however I wanted to add the lines at once without using a loop.  Adding the data at once is faster than looping but if what I am asking for is impossible I can just loop.

Why don't you want to use a loop?  What is the problem?

From my timing loop seems to be a tad slower.  But without pandas I am guessing loop is the way to go.

@newdeveloper what does using the csv module have to do with not writing a loop? You have a list of strings that themselves are just individual csv lines, as far as I can tell, which is not what the csv module is for. You could turn your individual strings into lists of integers, then use the csv module, or just write the strings you already have to a file without using the csv writer, because that isn't waht you want. Where does this list come from in the first place?

@newdeveloper what timing? What are you comparing? You have to loop somehow to write those lines to a file. Note, you could use file.writelines, but again, that is just a loop.

You don't need to use pandas as advised by Mark. You can do this with what you have.
Firstly, you will want to change quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL to quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL for this to work.
Secondly, your need to sort out the data list.
Currently it thinks 438.0337145,438.0178423,0.0158\n is one string. The quotes are added automatically on output as the strings contain commas and without them it will cause problems when opening or reading the CSV.
Either add more apostrophes to split them into individual strings, or remove the apostrophes to have floats (numbers).
You will then need to loop over each row and print them independently.
Try doing the following instead:
data = [
    [438.0337145,438.0178423,0.0158],
    [438.0497017,438.0337145,0.01598]
]

with open(uuidCSV, 'w') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(
        csvFile,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
        delimiter=","
    )

    for row in data:
        wr.writerow(row)


See the docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

With csv data that includes commas in the fields, I usually use the pandas csv tools and set pipes "|" as the delimiter. Something like this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path to file.csv", sep='|')

# Replace unwanted quotes
df['Column'] = df['Column'].astype(str).apply(lambda r: r.replace('\"',''))


I don't have access to pandas.

pandas seems like overkill.
